# Write down identities of binomial coefficients that are equal to the following identities

Tags: combinatorics

I was given the following task to prove

> Write down identities of binomial coefficients that are equal to the
> following identities,    $(a+b)^n = (a+b)^{n-1}(a+b)$
> $(a+b)^{n+m} = (a+b)^{n}(a+b)^m$

I do not understand this task. Could you please explain what I need to do and how should I start ?

Comment: Perhaps expand both sides using Binomial Theorem and compare the coefficients of $a^k b^{n-k}$ on both sides?

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. In particular, don't just say "I don't know where to start". The standard place to start is to look at your notes or book to see if there are related questions with worked solutions. Did you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first identity, we can re-write both sides using the binomial theorem:

$$ \begin{align}
\vphantom{} \\
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} a^{n-k} \, b^k &= (a+b) \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k} a^{n-1-k} \, b^k \\
\vphantom{} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k} a^{n-k} \, b^k + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k} a^{n-1-k} \, b^{k+1}\\
\vphantom{} \\
\end{align} $$

Now, replacing $k$ with $k-1$ in the second summation on the right side, we get

$$ \begin{align}
\vphantom{} \\
\qquad \qquad \;= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k} a^{n-k} \, b^k + \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n-1}{k-1} a^{n-k} \, b^{k}\\
\vphantom{} \\
\end{align} $$

Then, extracting first and last terms on the left side, and one first and one last term on the right, we have

$$ \begin{align}
\vphantom{} \\
a^n + b^n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} a^{n-k} \, b^k = \left[ a^n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k} a^{n-k} \, b^k \right] + \left[ b^n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k-1} a^{n-k} \, b^{k} \right]\\
\vphantom{} \\
\end{align} $$

Finally, equating coefficients in the remaining summations, we arrive at the identity

$$ \begin{align}
\vphantom{} \\
\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n-1}{k} + \binom{n-1}{k-1} \qquad \text{for} \quad 1 \le k \le n-1\\
\vphantom{} \\
\end{align} $$